# component.query versus component.getcomponent in performance

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

is component.query() faster than component.getComponent() ?

what are the pros and cons of using component.query ?

Comment: Downvoting is ok but may the damn down voters be so kind and leave comment!! I don't think that this question is so total stupid to get down votes without any comment. Without any comment the poster also get no chance to improve his question! So +1 to hold against this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `Ext.ComponentQuery` queries for all underlying Components (*you may define a traversing start as second param after the query string)* it also allow you to query by a various set of params, attributes, pseudo classes, functions, etc. **[Full Reference](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)** and always result in a set (array) `compinstance.GetComponent('itemId')` only queries the **direct** childs of the calling component for the `itemId` property and will always return one reference or null. Note that the `itemId` need only to be unique to all it's siblings.

So yes `GetComponent()` will be a bit faster.

I don't think that there are huge pros and cons. `GetComponent()` cannot be used that often because you may not only looking in level. Take a menu which groups the the buttons, `GetComponent()` will only find the group but not the anything within it. So don't care to much about it.